# Python Style Guide: Should print() commands be in or out of defs?

Tags: python

Which is more stylistically accepted to do?
This:

```
def example_function(stuff):
    thing = stuff
    print(thing)

example_function('words')
```

Or:

```
def example_function(stuff):
    thing = stuff
    return thing

print(example_function('words'))
```

I'm still figuring out my way through Python, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That really depends on what your function is doing, which shouldn't be called "function" according to the Python Style Guide.

Comment: Having the function return the string (or another object) is more flexible. Then you can still do something with that string (slice it, format it, use it somewhere else...)

Comment: @L3viathan Yeah, good point. Sorry.

Comment: @timgeb Thanks! That makes sense.

Comment: I agree with @timgeb and would say; rule of thumb: If what is printed is only useful for the user and couldn't ever be useful for another function, then I'd put it in the function. Otherwise, put it outside. And by the way, it should also not be called `a_function`, but instead after what it is actually doing. :P

Comment: Questions about style are usually off-topic here. But in addition to style, `print()` functions can mess up production code in some cases. Inside functions, use `logging` when you need to log something.

Comment: What about asking on Stack Exchange Code Review?

Comment: @palsch Ah, didn't know it existed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider how the function will be used. If it includes the `print`, you can *never* call the function *without* it producing output (ignoring monkey patching and the like). If it does not include the `print`, you can always print its return value explicitly if you decide you want to output the value.

In other words, lean towards printing a return value unless you have a very good reason to print from inside the function. Printing to standard output isn't actually as common as most beginner programs would leave you to believe. Most of the code one writes is intended to be used by other code, rather than communicating directly with a human.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a clue from the `__str__` and `__repr__` methods of objects.  They return a string representation, allowing you to do things like

```
print(dict(a=1))
print([1,2,3,4])
```

In general returning a string gives you more flexibility.

But while debugging code, I often include diagnostic print statements within a function.

The `argparse` module has:

```
parser.print_help()
parser.format_help()
```

methods.  The print calls the format, and takes a `file=None` parameter.  The default action is to write to `stdout` (or `stderr`) but the user can redirect it.